# Result of async function in react not ready for return elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a personal project that requires aync API calls in React

I make an API call, await the promise, parse it as JSON and move on here:

```
const getMatch = async (matchId) => {
        const response = await fetch(
            `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v4/matches/${matchId}?api_key=${API_KEY}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    };
```

I then loop through the JSON looking for a condition, which returns a true or a false so that a ternary can apply a class to a html element, here is the loop:

```
const didWin = async () => {
        var m = await getMatch(match.gameId);
        var pId, tId;
        for (var p in m.participantIdentities) {
            if (m.participantIdentities.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                if (m.participantIdentities[p].player.summonerName == profileName) {
                    pId = m.participantIdentities[p].participantId;
                }
            }
        }
        for (var x in m.participants) {
            if (m.participants.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
                if (m.participants[x].participantId == pId) {
                    tId = m.participants[x].teamId;
                }
            }
        }
        for (var t in m.teams) {
            if (m.teams.hasOwnProperty(t)) {
                if (m.teams[t].teamId == tId && m.teams[t].win == "Win") {
                    console.log(true);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(false);
        return false;
    };
```

Here can be seen the function above getting called and applying a class based on the return:

```
<div className={`card-footer ${didWin() ? "bg-success" : "bg-danger"}`}>
```

However after testing every single call of this react component always equates to true, which should not be the case and should at most times be 50/50 true false

To me it feels like the `didWin()` is not having time to finish checking before react will return the given html elements, defaulting the call to true

Is this the case? Is there something glaringly obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: `didWin() ? "bg-success" : "bg-danger"` this makes no sense. Async function always returns a Promise that is truthy.

Comment: Seems to me like you need to `await` for `didWin()` somewhere...

Comment: `didWin` returns promise object and in your conditional check it will be evaluated to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable like `won = false` and then change the variable value inside didWin method, this way you won't have a promised returned, and you will be reading a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using a flag value

```
state={
flag:false;
}
```

make it true when all the conditions are checked.
and the try rendering in react using if statement

```
{!this.state.flag? <some spinner>: <your div>
```

Comment: I have just tried `const [winFlag, setWinFlag] = useState()`, and instead of returning true/false in the method I setWinFlag instead, I call `didWin()` right before the return method and use `<div className={`card-footer ${winFlag ? "bg-success" : "bg-danger"}`}>`, to me it feels like the method is not resolving and setting winFlag before it gets returned, could this be the case?